# Dtls client doesn't send ClientHello with cookie

Tags: c++, openssl, client, dtls

I'm implementing dtls support for my sip client, using openssl. My SSL_connect returns SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, my 'select' to handle it always timeout. In wireshark I saw a first ClientHello and HelloVerifyRequest, but second ClientHello with cookie never came.

Comment: If you are the DTLS Client, then your code should be sending the ClientHello with Cookie. So, if you are not seeing it, there could be a error on your code.

Comment: You're right, there was another socket listening on the same port. Now after ServerHelloDone, wireshark showed Alert sent from client.
Debug on s_server show this

_SSL3 alert read:fatal:internal error
SSL_accept:failed in SSLv3 read client certificate A
ERROR
140528435164840:error:14102438:SSL routines:DTLS1_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error:d1_pkt.c:1173:SSL alert number 80_

Comment: Looks like Server is expecting Client to send it's certificate i.e. Client Authentication and Client doesn't have a certificate to send or Server Certificate Validation itself could have failed. What does the Debug message on Client Side?

Comment: this is the client side
_SSL_CB_HANDSHAKE_START before/connect initialization
SSL_CB_LOOP before/connect initialization
SSL_CB_LOOP SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL_CB_EXIT SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_CB_LOOP DTLS1 read hello verify request A
SSL_CB_LOOP SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL_CB_LOOP SSLv3 flush data
SSL_CB_EXIT SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_CB_LOOP SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_CB_LOOP SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_CB_EXIT SSLv3 read server key exchange A
SSL_CB_ALERT fatal internal error
SSL_CB_EXIT error_

Comment: Looks like it threw an error after ingesting SSL Certificate and Key Exchange Message. Most likely the Server Certificate Validation could have failed. Have you loaded the required CA Certificates required to validate the Server Certificate on the Client Side?

Comment: The same certificate works well with my TLS implementation. I only change the client method and cipher list for DTLS.

Comment: Btw, if I try to set SSL_VERIFY_PEER for client, the fatal now say "unknown CA".

Comment: @Jay I try 'openssl verify' on the cert on server and it turns out _error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate_ . Does this mean my certificate is wrong?

Comment: Are you using self-signed certificate itself as Server Certificate?

Comment: Yes, this is how I request certificate for server `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes`

Comment: In that case, you will also have to add that certificate as a local CA on the client side.

Comment: My client is on Windows, and I have import the certificate to Trusted Root CA folder, but still not working

Comment: Sorry Cuong, Looks like without having a look at the direct system, it will be difficult to debug this.

Comment: Thanks anw, @Jay, really appreciate your help. Just one more question, is there a chance that server certificate is OK but server key exchange failed?

Comment: It could be if the algorithm used is something RSA-DHE and the key exchange parameters are incorrect. But, such cases are unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that there was another socket listening on the same port.  I fixed that and there was second ClientHello with cookie. I still have other problem later on, but will raise another question. Thanks.